# check the values in a mysql column (in a set) , separate them and doing operation on them

Tags: php, mysql

I have mysql column that the user will enter data into that like this:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `a_classes` = CONCAT(a_classes, '$class_id_insert') WHERE id='$st_id'
```

and data will insert into column with this filter: 1,2,3...

How is it possible to check inserted data into one column and prevent entering duplicate number.

for example if we had this data in that column: 1,2,3,4 and the user entered 4 , he receive an error?

Comment: you need to code a trigger for that